# Will MySQL works with RemoteFX and Hyper-V R2?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 and currently running MySQL on it. However, this server is the only Windows Server 2008 than I have. I also want to test the RemoteFX on Hyper-V and a RDP.

Now, I only want to use this as a test but I don't want to break anything related to MySQL.

Will I be able to install RemoteFX along with Hyper-V and not effecting MySQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherent to Hyper-V or RemoteFX that would conflict with MySQL.

Comment: So I should be able to install RemoteFX and Hyper-V on the same server where MySQL is installed this will not effect the MySQL server and this will not effect the connection going to MySQL at all? I am double checking because MySQL is in production and I don't want to effect it.

Comment: Don't do it. Production servers are not for testing. Also, a reboot will be required to enable Hyper-V and RemoteFX.

Comment: I know production server is not for testing but the problem is that this is the only server. It is is production but not used consistently so I can reboot and do things on it but I can't stop MySQL Server for a long time or break MySQL because I installed those futures.